# Special character when exporting SQL query results to CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I exported my SQL query results into a CSV file using the BCP command. All my records are properly exported and formatted except only one record having special characters at the end like `B0013467?`.

My SQL record doesn't have this character in its value. But how come it got amended while exporting results to the CSV file? I even opened with Notepad. The special character still remained in exported results.

Please advise. My BCP command is like this:

```
bcp "select * from ##OutputTable3" queryout "' + @Path + '\Temp_RawData3.csv" -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -T -t , -c
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the specific column for the special character using the following code ,which will give you the Hex values of the characters.

```
cast (MyColumn as varbinary(max))
```

---

0x430030003000300031003600390039003300**0E20**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

Comment: Hi i think there is some trailing space in my field. I just updated by deleting the space and now the export is fine. But when using bcp -w this will eliminate trailing space. But this is overriding -c which i used for field terminator. Hence my result will be , seperated not in seperated cell. Id there any way i can achieve both?

Comment: Space wouldn't have been displayed as `?`. Please  add the results of `cast (MyColumn as varbinary(max))`

Comment: This is the result from the above command 0x4300300030003000310036003900390033000E20

Comment: Will RTRIM() remove this special character?

Comment: @LT268, No. `declare @str nchar(1) = cast(0x0E20 as nchar(1)) select cast(rtrim(@str) as varbinary(1))` however you can use REPLACE